# How to dynamically set constraints for a custom table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom table view cell with following constraints, one for `UILabel` and one for `UIImageView`:

```swift
var titleLabel = UILabel()
var imageView = UIImageView()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    addSubview(titleLabel)
    
    setTitlelabelConstraints()
    setImageConstraints()
}

func setTitlelabelConstraints() {
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
    titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
}

func setImageConstraints() {
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 16/9).isActive = true
}
```

How do I conditionally set the leading anchor to be 0 so that when there is no image, the text label takes up the entire cell? The static constraints currently leave an empty space if there is no image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort of do this: Make the image view width constraint a less-than-or-equal constraint, and add another image view width constraint with constant 0 and priority 700.

However, that won't really solve your problem. After all, you will still have the spacing between the image view and label. The *real* answer lies in your own words: "static". Don't make them static! Change the constraints depending on whether there's an image or not. After all, you know, for each cell, whether there's an image, so this is all part of your configuration.

Constraints are full-fledged objects, so as you make the image view width constraint and the label leading constraint, keep references to them, and now you can just set the width to 0 and the spacing to 0 when there is no image.

In this screencast, all I'm doing is removing/adding the image and changing the constants. I added the animation just for fun but of course you wouldn't do that.

[image]

Comment: I thought of was passing a value from `cellForRowAt` to the custom table view cell that tells the cell that there is an image or not and set the constraints accordingly, but the only issue is that the constraints are set in `viewDidLoad` so I'm not quite sure how to deploy functions in `viewDidLoad` conditionally.

Comment: But in `cellForRowAt` you configure the cell. You can do anything you want. And as I just showed, one of those things is to change the constraints. — And I don't know what you mean about the constraints being set in `viewDidLoad`. A cell has no `viewDidLoad`. Your code shows that the constraints are set in `init`, which is fine. And I'm saying, fine, so change them in `cellForRowAt`. And I told you how to do that; keep a reference to them, as an instance property, just like the image view and the label are instance properties.